flask table with css
This code doesn't works.
Python code:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template
#import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.abspath('../templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.abspath('../static')

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=TEMPLATE_DIR, static_folder=STATIC_DIR)

# datetime object containing current date and time
day = datetime.now()

print(f"now ={day}")

nomi = ['Mario', 'Gianluca', 'Nicola', 'Andrea', 'Simone']
date = []
date.append('Nomi')

for i in range(40):
    delta = timedelta(days=(i-(40/2)))
    append_day = day+delta
    displ_str = append_day.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    print(displ_str)
    date.append(displ_str)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = date)
df['Nomi'] = nomi

@app.route('/', methods=("POST", "GET"))
def html_table():

    # link_column is the column that I want to add a button to
    return render_template("patient_list2.html", column_names=df.columns.values, 
row_data=list(df.values.tolist()), link_column="Patient ID", zip=zip)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')

Html code:
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Document with python</title>
     <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/patient_list.css') }}" 
     rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
 </head>
 <body>
     <table>
         <tr>
             {% for col in column_names %}
             <th>{{col}}</th>
             {% endfor %}
         </tr>
         {% for row in row_data %}
         <tr>
             {% for col, row_ in zip(column_names, row) %}
             {% if col == link_column %}
             <td>
                <button type="submit" value={{ row_ }} name="person_id" 
 form="patient_form" class="patient_button">
                {{ row_ }}
            </button>
        </td>
        {% else %}
        <td>{{row_}}</td>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

   </table>
</body>

CSS code:
table{
display: flex;
border: 2px solid darkblue;
font-size: medium;
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
overflow-x: auto;
}

td, th {
border: 1px solid #121111;
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #d6e0ee;
}

tr:first-child {
background-color: yellowgreen;
}

It returns following errors:
[2024-08-20 12:00:15,876] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mnardo\Desktop\Pers\Flask_Prj\hello_flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\mnardo\Desktop\Pers\Flask_Prj\hello_flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\mnardo\Desktop\Pers\Flask_Prj\hello_flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\mnardo\Desktop\Pers\Flask_Prj\hello_flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "C:\Users\mnardo\Desktop\Pers\Flask_Prj\hello_flask\showTable.py", line 35, in html_table
    return render_template("patient_list2.html", column_names=df.columns.values, row_data=list(df.values.tolist()), link_column="Patient ID", zip=zip)
  File "C:\Users\mnardo\Desktop\Pers\Flask_Prj\hello_flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 149, in render_template
    template = app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list)
  File "C:\Users\mnardo\Desktop\Pers\Flask_Prj\hello_flask\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1084, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "C:\Users\mnardo\Desktop\Pers\Flask_Prj\hello_flask\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1013, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, globals)
  File "C:\Users\mnardo\Desktop\Pers\Flask_Prj\hello_flask\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 972, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "C:\Users\mnardo\Desktop\Pers\Flask_Prj\hello_flask\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 126, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "C:\Users\mnardo\Desktop\Pers\Flask_Prj\hello_flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 65, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "C:\Users\mnardo\Desktop\Pers\Flask_Prj\hello_flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 99, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: patient_list2.html
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Aug/2024 12:00:15] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Could you please give me a help to understand what is the error?

Did you check what is the value for TEMPLATE_DIR? What is the contents of templates folder? Is there patient_list2.html in it?

You are right, the problem was the bad value of TEMPLATE_DIR and STATIC_DIR.

The problem was the wrong value of TEMPLATE_DIR and STATIC_DIR, Fixing them all the code works correctly.
The correct value is:
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.abspath('../Flask_Prj/hello_flask/templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.abspath('../Flask_Prj/hello_flask/templates/static')

